# Get Drive names from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

In PowerShell on a Windows 2016 installation I can do a `Get-Disk` command to figure out the name of the installed drives. This doesn't seem to be supported in Windows Server 2012. What is the correct way of figuring out the drive names through PowerShell and then assigning those strings to a variable to be used later?

Comment: What name exactly do you need? (Which property of `Get-Disk`.)

Comment: I believe friendly name should do it.

Comment: According to TechNet it is supported on 2012: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848657(v=wps.620).aspx. Are you getting an error? _doesn't seem to be supported_ is not conclusive

Comment: Co-worker told me that it wouldn't work...But he appears to be wrong. So then, what is the correct command to make the friendly name a string variable?

Comment: `[string[]]$aVariable = ( Get-Disk ).FriendlyName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

```
Get-Disk | % {$_.FriendlyName}
```

Which is similar to this

```
foreach($disk in Get-Disk){
    $disk.FriendlyName
}
```

Comment: Let me give this a try when windows finally finishes up all of the upgrades

Comment: That works. Is there a simple way to assign the names to variables?

Comment: The name is the `$_.FriendlyName`.

Answer (score 0):

Not the same as `FriendlyName`, but maybe suitable for your use-case

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_DiskDrive).Model
```